# Maximum number of consecutive occurrences of a value by group in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I have time-ordered data (e.g. transactions on account) and for each account I have a date and an indicator whether transaction is greater than certain threshold (e.g. $100). I would like to calculate for each account what is the maximum number of consecutive transactions with value above $100.

I have a solution, but it requires three steps for data transformation and a final aggregation. Is there a smarter way how to approach this? For the sample data below the number I am looking for is:

```
--seq 1 --> result 3
--seq 2 --> result 1

/*
select * from tmp_is_something;
drop table tmp_is_something;
-- seq - order of the transaction (1 = most recent)
-- part - account id
-- expr - 1 = transaction > $100, 0 = transaction <= $100
create table tmp_is_something (seq number, part number, expr number);
insert into tmp_is_something values(1,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(2,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(3,1,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(4,1,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(5,1,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(6,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(7,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(8,1,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(9,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(10,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(11,1,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(12,1,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(1,2,1);
insert into tmp_is_something values(2,2,0);
insert into tmp_is_something values(3,2,1);
commit;
*/
```

The query is:

```
with t as (
  select 
    seq, 
    part, 
    expr, 
    count(*) over(partition by part) as cnt,
    case when expr <> coalesce(lag(expr, 1) over(partition by part order by seq), expr) then 1 else 0 end as change_to_prev,  
    row_number() over(partition by part order by seq) as rn
  from tmp_is_something
) 

, u  as (
  select 
    seq, part, expr, cnt, rn, change_to_prev, 
    sum(change_to_prev) 
         over (partition by part order by seq rows between unbounded preceding and current row) + 1 as flip_sequence
  from t 
)

, v as (
  select 
    part, 
    flip_sequence, 
    count(*) cnt, 
    max(expr) expr, 
    max(rn) last_rn, 
    max(rn) - count(*) rn_diff 
  from 
    u
  group by 
    part, 
    flip_sequence
)

select 
  part,
  listagg( expr || '-' || cnt || '; ') within group (order by flip_sequence) as seq_str,
  max(expr * cnt) max_con_is
from v
group by part;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use analytical `sum()` twice to create grouping column based on continuous data, then use this column for further analysis:

**<sup>[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/028cb/1)</sup>**

```
select part, max(cnt) cnt
  from (select part, grp, count(1) cnt 
          from (select tmp.*, 
                       sum(1) over (partition by part order by seq) 
                       - sum(expr) over (partition by part order by seq) grp
                  from tmp)
          where expr = 1 group by part, grp)
  group by part
```

Comment: Looks like the difference is equal to `sum(decode(expr, 0, 1, 0)) over (partition by part order by seq)`. Correct? Also is there a reason you are using `sum(1)` instead of `row_number()`?

Comment: Yes, seems like summing negated expr gives the same effect, good find! `row_number()` or `sum(1)` is exchangable if `seq` is unique within partitions, if it's not then `row_number()` may generate wrong output.